# C# bool and turn on off function with neat way?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I got following code.

```
public class MpChange : CusEffect
{
    bool AlreadyDo = false;
    bool AlreadyStop = false;

    public override void CondDel(object sender, CondEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CondMet && !AlreadyDo)
        {
            DoEffect();
            AlreadyDo = true;
            AlreadyStop = false;
        }
        else if (!e.CondMet && !AlreadyStop)
        {
            StopEffect();
            AlreadyStop = true;
            AlreadyDo = false;
        } 
    }

    public override void DoEffect()
    {
        Debug.Log(WhoEffect.name + "'s Mp changed +5");
    }
    
    public override void StopEffect()
    {
        Debug.Log(WhoEffect.name + "'s Mp changed -5");
    }
}
```

This is called when character's hp is full, (then DoEffect()), and if not full, then StopEffect().

When character's hp is changed, event published and this MpChange class is subscribe it.

In this case, can this code be neat?

I hate to using this 2 boolean variables (AlreadyDo, AlreadyStop), being confused.

Comment: This seems like a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: So why not use only one? :D

Comment: If use only one, then at first character get Hp damage, StopEffect does not called because e.CondMet is coming as false, and AlreadyDo is false.

Answer (score 2):

One boolean will do:

```
    bool State = false;
    public override void CondDel(object sender, CondEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CondMet == State) return;  // nothing to do, state's the current one
        State = !State;  // flip the flag
        if (State) {  // do or undo a thing
            DoEffect();
        } else {
            StopEffect();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for neat way, but with this, at first character's hp got damage, StopEffect does not called, but it should be. If test with like 3 damage to HP, and heal 3 points to HP repeatedely, result is.... (nothing happen when first 3 damage) -> +5 mp changed (normal by DoEffect) -> -5 mp changed (normal by StopEffect) -> .. -> .. and so on.

Comment: So its because when got HP damage, e.CondMet coming as false, but at this first point (when it happens first time), State var is also false, so be returned.

Answer (score 1):

So instead using boolean, I should use enum.

I set,

```
public enum ConditionState
{
None, Complete, Incomplete,
}
```

and change condition code part based on enum state and prevent duplicate calling,

```
public abstract class CusCondition
{
public bool Earned;      
public int SealValueCond;
public ConditionState conditionMet;
private ConditionState prevCond = ConditionState.None;
[HideInInspector]
public Character WhoCondition;       
public virtual void ConditionEvent(object sender, MyEventArgs myEventArgs)
{
    SealManager.Instance.PublishEvent(this, new CondEventArgs(conditionMet));
}
public virtual void ConditionEventState(object sender, MyEventArgs myEventArgs)
{       // execute only once state changes 
    if (conditionMet == prevCond) return;
    prevCond = conditionMet;
    SealManager.Instance.PublishEvent(this, new CondEventArgs(conditionMet));
}
}
```

and then at effect part, this is enough.

```
public override void CondDel(object sender, CondEventArgs e)
{ 
    if (e.CondMet == ConditionState.Complete)
        DoEffect();
    else if(e.CondMet == ConditionState.Incomplete)
        StopEffect();
}
```